# Extract numbers within text VBA/Excel

Tags: string, vba, text, numbers, extract

Looking for some suggestions to tweak/enhance the formula I have created, to extract the number from a string.

Have the below sample text in a Cell A1:

Based on the invnum:-1234567 The calculation is based on 123.33*3.00

Wrote the below formula in B1

```
=VALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("invnum:-",A1)+7,LEN((A1))),7)
```

the Result given is -1234567

However, the length of the reference number on my source file is variable, Looking to extract only the number following the word invnum:-

Looking to include this formula in a macro, so trying to keep it simple any ideas/suggestions please?

Comment: I assume there are other words after the number?  Can you show the entire string in a couple of cells?

Comment: Amount due for 02/29/2016 is Based on the invnum:-1234567 The calculation is based on 123.33*3.0

Comment: Amount due for 03/01/2016 is Based on the invnum:-178634 The calculation is based on 345.90*56.85 amended as per request

Comment: Partial amount due for 03/02/2016 is Based on the invnum:-178634 The calculation is based on 89.54*5.32

Comment: Hi Scott - I have the above in Cells A1, A2, A3 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try this Function:

```
Function findNumber(inPtStr As String) As Double
    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    inPtStr = Replace(inPtStr, ":", " ")
    strArr = Split(inPtStr)
    For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
        If IsNumeric(strArr(i)) Then
            findNumber = --strArr(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Then you can call it from a regular sub.

If you want a formula then:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),FIND("invnum:",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)))+7,99))
```

Comment: @Sas Please mark as correct, by clicking on the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It will mark the question as answered.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get crazy and step through this...

Start with the intermediate indexes you need to find, such as the start, end, and length of the numeric string. Once you have those, just **carefully** reassemble your formula:

[image]